# HTML & CSS - Center image in website

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center an image but it doesn't works :(

I use the parameter text-align: center;. The size of the image is 600x600px and I need to center horizontal in the website.

My code is:

```css
#share-buttons img {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  display: inline;
}
.img-sugar{
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="assets/css-styles/custom-login-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <img class="img-sugar" src="assets/images/SUGAR.png"/><br><br><br>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <form action="shareimage.php" method="post">
        <input class="" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row" id="share-buttons">

    <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
      <!-- Facebook -->
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
      </a>
      <!-- Twitter -->
      <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://simplesharebuttons.com&amp;text=Simple%20Share%20Buttons&amp;hashtags=simplesharebuttons" target="_blank">
        <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>
```

At moment it shows:

[image]

Could you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: can you provide this code in fiddle

Comment: you could use this two statements vertical-align: middle;
   text-align: center;

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this code for the `.img-sugar`CSS:

```
.img-sugar{
   width: 600px;
   height: 600px;
   display: block;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this css, you have some syntax error and spelling mistake

```
    .img-sugar{
        max-width: 600px;
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        text-align: center;
      }
```

```css
#share-buttons img {
  width: 50px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 0;
  box-shadow: 0;
  display: inline;
}

.img-sugar{
  max-width: 600px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WebCam UI</title>

      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="assets/css-styles/custom-login-style.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                     <img class="img-sugar" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"/><br><br><br>
          </div>

        </div>

      <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
            <form action="shareimage.php" method="post">
              <input class="" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera"/>
            </form>
          </div>

      </div>

      <div class="row" id="share-buttons">

        <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <!-- Facebook -->
          <a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=https://simplesharebuttons.com" target="_blank">
            <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/facebook.png" alt="Facebook" />
          </a>
          <!-- Twitter -->
          <a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=https://simplesharebuttons.com&amp;text=Simple%20Share%20Buttons&amp;hashtags=simplesharebuttons" target="_blank">
              <img src="https://simplesharebuttons.com/images/somacro/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" />
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would insert your img via css it would be easiely done with this here:

```
.img{ 
    background:url(yourimg.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```
.img-sugar{
    width: 600px;
    weight: 600px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    vertical-align: center;
    horizontal-align: center;
}
```

maybe this works?

Answer (score 0):

`margin: 0 auto` you forgot to end with semicolon `;`

```
.img-sugar{
   width: 600px;
   weight: 600px;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 auto;
   text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below mentioned Padding value.

```
#share-buttons img {
    width: 50px;
    padding: 100px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: 0;
    display: inline;
  }
```